# Why can't Notepad in Window 11 save a .ora file?

Tags: windows, notepad, oracle

I'm having a challenge editing a sqlnet.ora file in my Oracle network/admin folder with the build in notepad.exe in Windows 11

Whenever I try to save the file, Notepad insists on appending .txt to it.

I can get it to save as a .bat file, a .sql file and even a .exe file. However .ora seems to be forbidden some how.

Is there a setting I can change around this?

(I know... workarounds are Notepad++ and gvim and <your_favourite> and renaming afterwards)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP says the problem is solved.

Comment: A problem being solved doesn't mean the post should be closed. They gave an answer that should help others, making this a good addition for SuperUser, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found... Inheritance Property (security->Advance) was turned off for the file.

While I did have permission to write to the folder, the .ora file I was editing did not have that permission.

Instead of telling me I couldn't overwrite it, Notepad made the decision to add the .txt extension.

Comment: +1 because it might be useful to others -- Notepad is *not* alerting user of issue.